# Why doesn't Ubuntu support the command 'sh example.sh'?

Tags: command-line, scripts

Why doesn't Ubuntu support `sh example.sh` command?

It's more convenient than `cd $wd; ./example.sh` and `add PATH` in some situation.

`login.sh`:

```
~/bin/logmitgw.sh -i 4564646 dfdsfsdf
```

`logmitgw.sh`:

```
some code
```

When I'm running  `sh ~/bin/login.sh`

I get:

```
sh: 0: Can't open ~/bin/login.sh
```

`ls -l ~/bin/login.sh` outputs `-rwxrwxr-x`

Comment: What is `cd $wd`?

Comment: change working directory to the shell directory

Comment: You need to be more specific about your problem. The example you gave (`sh example.sh`) should work, unless the script you are trying to execute requires another shell or interpreter different from `sh`.

Comment: @Salem I have edited my question.

Comment: You didn't actually answer the first question... what is `cd $wd`?  This could only work if you have something like `wd=~/bin` defined elsewhere, but why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the script is in ~/bin then ~/bin will already be in the path.  As long as it's a bash script you can execute it from anywhere at all.  No need to shell, no need to cd, and no need to add anything in your path.

eg:

```
login.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu does support running `sh example.sh`. That works fine if you do everything else right. The problem in your case *seems* to be that you are giving the incorrect path to the script.

---

When you open a terminal in Ubuntu, it most likely starts a Bash shell. I will assume that to be the case for you.

Also, the command `sh` calls a different shell:

```
$ command -v sh
/usr/bin/sh
$ ls -l /usr/bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Aug  4 11:43 /usr/bin/sh -> /usr/bin/dash
```

That is, `/usr/bin/sh` is a symlink to the [dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almquist_shell) shell. On some systems, the `sh` symlink may be to another shell.

One thing that might go wrong, is that there is no `sh` in the system.

Here is an example script:

```
$ echo 'echo "works!"' > ~/bin/example.sh
$ sh ~/bin/example.sh
works!
```

If I delete the `sh` symlink, I get an error:

```
$ sudo rm /usr/bin/sh
$ sh ~/bin/example.sh
bash: /usr/bin/sh: No such file or directory
```

Note that this is not the error you got.

I ran `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/dash /usr/bin/sh` to make the symlink again and get my `sh` back.

Another problem could be that the file is not a shell script, and dash is not able to run it, or it is a shell script, but it is not compatible with dash. In that case, you will get a syntax error of some kind, for example:

```
$ file /bin/bash
/bin/bash: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=a6cb40078351e05121d46daa768e271846d5cc54, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped
$ sh /bin/bash
/bin/bash: 1: ELF: not found
/bin/bash: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
$ file /usr/bin/uname
/usr/bin/uname: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=3354931bca4ff072b26258a956ffde08ead5f341, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped
$ sh /usr/bin/uname
/usr/bin/uname: 1: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

But you did not get an error like that.

When the dash shell is asked to run a file that does not exist, it outputs the error you show in your question:

```
$ ls ~/bin/anything
ls: cannot access '/home/zanna/bin/anything': No such file or directory
$ sh ~/bin/anything
sh: 0: Can't open /home/zanna/bin/anything
```

The `0` in this error is the current file:

```
$ echo 'echo $0' > ~/bin/something
$ sh ~/bin/something
/home/zanna/bin/something
```

In your question, you say that you ran

```
sh ~/bin/login.sh
```

and got

```
sh: 0: Can't open ~/bin/login.sh
```

But that error does not make sense, because the tilde `~` should be expanded to the path of your home directory. Remember my error:

```
$ sh ~/bin/anything
sh: 0: Can't open /home/zanna/bin/anything
                     ^___^------expansion of ~
```

I can reproduce your error by quoting the path:

```
$ sh ~/bin/example.sh 
works!
$ sh "~/bin/example.sh" 
sh: 0: Can't open ~/bin/example.sh
```

Maybe that is what you did.

Or, looking at [the revision history of your post](https://askubuntu.com/posts/218725/revisions), it seems you may have run

```
sh /bin/login.sh
```

That does not work, and will output `sh: 0: Can't open /bin/login.sh` unless there is a file `login.sh` in the top level directory `/bin`. You would probably know if you had created such a file, because you would have had to do so as root.

Another reason why you would get the error `sh: 0: Can't open /path/to/file`, is that you ran `sh ~/bin/login.sh` but there was no such file. But, the `~` would still have been expanded in that case. Also, you give the first part of the output of `ls -l` for your file, to show the permissions:

> ```
> -rwxrwxr-x
> ```

So, apparently, `~/bin/login.sh` is a regular file with permissions 775. So perhaps that was not the problem.

Note that, when you call an interpreter, such as (da)sh, to run a script, the script need not have execute permission:

```
$ ls -l ~/bin/example.sh
-rw-rw-r-- 1 zanna zanna 14 Aug  4 11:36 /home/zanna/bin/example.sh
$ sh ~/bin/example.sh 
works!
```

But your script calls another script, without calling an interpreter to run it. That would cause a permission error if the second script had no execute permission:

```
$ echo '~/bin/example.sh' > ~/bin/something
$ sh ~/bin/something
/home/zanna/bin/something: 1: /home/zanna/bin/example.sh: Permission denied
```

But, once again, this is not the error you got.

You accepted [the answer by fabricator4](https://askubuntu.com/a/218736/527764), which pointed out that `~/bin` is added to PATH if it exists (you can see the code that does this in `~/.profile`), so if you have an executable in `~/bin`, you can run it without specifying the interpreter, but for that to work, the file must have execute permission:

```
$ example.sh
bash: /home/zanna/bin/example.sh: Permission denied
$ chmod u+x ~/bin/example.sh
$ example.sh
works!
```

(Here though the current shell, which we are assuming is Bash, and probably not dash, executes the script, in the absence of any [interpreter directive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_directive))

Since that answer worked for you, then it seems that the file existed, it had execute permission, and was a script compatible with Bash. What went wrong with your attempt to run it with the syntax `sh example.sh` then, seems to have been that you either quoted the path and prevented tilde expansion, or omitted the `~` entirely, thus, in either case, specifying the wrong path to your file.